Comment traduire "Respect hazards" sans que ça ne semble un calque de l'anglais
J'essaie de traduire, dans une présentation sur la santé et sécurité au travail:
"Respect hazards"
avec un texte qui indique de rester conscient, de ne pas être complaisant. "Respecter le(s) danger(s)" sonne comme un calque de l'anglais, à mon oreille. J'ai l'impression qu'en anglais, ça indique des gestes actifs, concrets relatif au danger potentiel. En français, « respecter » semble s'appliquer spécifiquement aux règles, aux lois, aux normes (ce que les dangers ne sont pas).
Est-ce qu'il y aurait un meilleur verbe?

Pouvez-vous fournir plus de contexte, par exemple, un peu plus du texte autour de ces deux mots?

We respect hazards – incident investigations identify lack of hazard awareness as an underlying cause of many process safety events; from the O+G industry: https://www.imca-int.com/safety-events/process-safety-fundamentals-iogp-step-change/

You have to decide here whether to just translate the meaning or if what you translate will be put on a sign, like in my link. Just saying, context matters. Attention aux risques. ? respecter ne marcherait pas.


ne pas négliger les aléas/risques.


In fact, "respecter les dangers" would not be a good translation.
This phrase can be translated in various ways as follows, using a verbal phrases.

rester conscient des dangers (existants/présents/possibles/)

rester en alerte face aux dangers (existants/présents/possibles/)

rester sur ses gardes face aux dangers

ne pas oublier les dangers (existants/présents/possibles/)

prendre garde aux dangers (existants/présents/possibles/)


Choisir son destin
Laure Elicia · 2024) Je ne pense pas qu'il prendrait une telle décision s'il ne se sentait pas capable de rester alerte face à un potentiel danger.

"Rester en alerte aux dangers" - pas trop.

Plutôt: rester vigilant face aux dangers.

"Rester en alerte face aux dangers" - ce n'est pas le sens de l'original. "Rester alerte" sans ce en pourrait aller.

@Frank « en alerte » signifie « sur ses gardes ».

"rester en alerte" n'est pas tout à fait la même chose que "rester alerte". Par exemple: "les pompiers sont restés en alerte toute la nuit" et "il faut rester alerte sur la route".

Ces solutions laissent un peu tomber la notion de respect, pour aller vers une notion de vigilance.
